# Set inline-block divs to ignore line breaks

Tags: html, css

I have three divs that are side-by-side using `display:inline-block`.

If the divs are empty, they are at the same horizontal level.

As soon as I add `<p>` tags and some line breaks (`<br/>`) to the leftmost/first div, the rest are moved down.

If I put enough content in the second box, the third is moved down even more.

My HTML for the boxes:

```
<div class="main-box" id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>This box has one paragraph of text, with line breaks</p>
</div>

<div id="login-container">
    <div class="main-box" id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <p>Already a member? Sign in and see your stuff!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-box" id="signup">
        <h1>Signup</h1>
        <p>Create an account by filling out this form.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The last two boxes are grouped in a div so that they "float" together.

My CSS:

```
div.main-box {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 10px solid red;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
div#login-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
 vertical-align: top;
```

You can read about `inline-block` and some more details like IE7 fix and spacing in html code [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to use float: left instead of display: inline-block for the inside divs?

Another solution that I can think of is to create a class with float: left or display: table and applying it to the paragraph tags.

Comment: I started with that but I can't easily center align.